# Magento : Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) with the same id “####” already exist

Tags: magento, version, admin, addition, magento-1.9.1

I have a issue here on `Magento`.

When I tried to add a customer in `Mangeto admin` side it is giving error something like

> Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) with the same id "14" already exist"

I am adding customer with Store Id selected as `Admin` store.

My `Magento` current version is `1.9.1`

Please advise!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891795/magento-item-mage-customer-model-customer-duplicate-issue

Comment: Should better be asked at Magento.SE, and is probably answered there: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40884/how-can-i-fix-item-mage-catalog-model-product-with-the-same-id-xxx-already