# Magento: Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) duplicate issue?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I have recently upgraded magento on my ecomerce store from `Magento 1.9` to `1.9.1`. Site is working OK after upgrade, but now I am seeing a strange issue when adding customers from admin panel.

While adding customers, I am selecting store id as `Admin` as shown below:

[image]

If I select `Main Website` as associated website then it works OK, but I just want to know why it is not working and giving error with "Admin", whereas in another Magento based store, I am not seeing such issue.

I am getting following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) with the same id "14" already exist";i:1;s:4825:"#0 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(265): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#1 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1055): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addItem(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#2 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#3 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#4 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php(61): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#5 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#6 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#7 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#8 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#10 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#11 /home/ecom/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#12 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/ecom/pu...')
#13 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#14 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#18 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#20 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#22 /home/ecom/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#23 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/ecom/pu...')
#24 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#25 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#26 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(83): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->indexAction()
#32 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /home/ecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /home/ecom/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /home/ecom/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}";s:3:"url";s:70:"/index.php/admin/customer/index/key/6f4763d319ecbe9ece8c009ea996b159/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I tried this fix: https://support.webcto.eu/index.php/Knowledgebase/Article/View/50/8/item-mage_catalog_model_product-with-the-same-id-already-exist it is working, but I don't think it is good idea to modify Magento's main core.

Please check and advise what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891015/magento-item-mage-customer-model-customer-with-the-same-id-already-ex

Comment: Should better be asked at Magento.SE, and is probably answered there: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40884/how-can-i-fix-item-mage-catalog-model-product-with-the-same-id-xxx-already